# Localizations files not available on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

Well, I received this project from a buddy that used to work with me and now I am responsible for it Internalization. I need to transform the language of the app to English, that is currently Portuguese.

Although i was researching for some tutorials but all of them include one step i cannot make. I have noticed there were no files localized in any of the languages, and no folders .Iproj too.

In the info tab > Localizations shows up, in each language added in my "Resources" Tab, "0 Files Located".

as Soon as i click "Use Base Internationalization" or the "plus" button there is no file i can reference it to.

I need to follow with this project and cannot create another one, there is lots of code and configurations that need to stay in this one. Is there any solutions?

Thanks!

PS: StackOverflow won't let me post images yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever visited this panel?

[image]